# Is there any Windows IDE with CMake support?

Tags: windows, ide, cross-platform, cmake

I'm developing game in Linux using CMake and KDevelop and I'd like to make it cross-platform.

I'm looking any Windows IDE with good CMake support like Kdevelop has, autocompletion, project building and launching should be enough to write some platform specific code.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using KDevelop and it always uses `cmake` to generate Makefiles before each build. So it has it integrated with it's build system.

Comment: Qtcreator has support of CMake project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Eclipse CDT, which is advocated to be cross platform and should behave well on Windows platform; then run cmake GUI to generate CDT project files so you can open them using Eclipse.

Another option is to generate Visual Studio `sln` files which can be opened in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are several IDEs supporting natively CMake (Not exhaustive list):

- QtCreator
- KDevelop ( you have a windows version, however last time I tried, it was significantly worse than the Linux version )
  ...

There are also some IDEs which do **not** support CMake, but CMake made hacks to you can generate project for them:

- Visual Studio
- Xcode
- Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Visual Studio does support CMake.

Comment: @bug: You probably mean that CMake has implemented a special generator to produce Visual Studio projects right? When I try to open a CMakeFiles.txt file with Microsoft Visual Studio, it won't understand it (you can see the text, but it won't read the project).

Comment: @AdrianMaire No, VS2019 actually integrates CMake support (and last I checked, used Ninja to execute the build commands): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160

Comment: Yeah, in fact support has been present since VS2017, which also added the ability to open an arbitrary folder as a "project".  Support is not entirely seamless and does make some assumptions about the layout of `CMakeFiles.txt`, but this seemed to be largely true of other IDEs with CMake integration too.